# Gmaps4Rails Gmaps.triggerOldOnload method not found javascript error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, gmaps4rails

I'm using the amazing gem gmaps4rails in a Rails project. It works just fine on my local machine, but once deployed on Heroku's Cedar stack the javascript throws an error at `window.onload = function() { Gmaps.triggerOldOnload(); Gmaps.loadMaps(); };` , complaining that triggerOldOnload doesn't exist on Gmaps. Again, it works fine locally.

Here is the entire script block in which the error appears:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
Gmaps.map = new Gmaps4RailsGoogle();
Gmaps.load_map = function() {
Gmaps.map.map_options.auto_adjust = true;
Gmaps.map.initialize();
Gmaps.map.markers = [{"title":"Project 1","lat":18.71381,"lng":-72.35581},    {"title":"Project 2","lat":18.71567,"lng":-72.35603}];
Gmaps.map.markers_conf.do_clustering = true;
Gmaps.map.create_markers();
Gmaps.map.adjustMapToBounds();
Gmaps.map.callback();
};
Gmaps.oldOnload = window.onload;
 window.onload = function() { Gmaps.triggerOldOnload(); Gmaps.loadMaps(); };
</SCRIPT>
```

Thanks in advance for looking this over!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you updated the gem but didn't rerun the command to copy the assets in your app.

Comment: I did, but it didn't solve the problem on Heroku. I see there is a later version than what I have so I am going to update to latest version and try it all again from scratch. I'll post the results.

Comment: Okay, I updated the gem to the latest version, and again executed `rails generate gmaps4rails:install.` The gem continues to work in my development environment, and continues to throw a javascript error in production because it can't find the triggerOldOnload method. This really is an awesome gem and I am perplexed as to why it generates that error in production.

Comment: did you recompile your assets? I fear you've some cache somewhere.

Comment: I have done `rake assets:precompile` more times than I count count. I have deleted all of the gmaps4rails files and used the rake install to put them back and then recompiled again. I just can't pin this down and it's making me CRAZY!

Comment: mmmm... do you have a public url so that I can check?

Comment: I don't know if this will be helpful or not. The js pulled into my local environment is `window.onload = function() { Gmaps.loadMaps(); };` but the js pulled into the production environment is `window.onload = function() { Gmaps.triggerOldOnload(); Gmaps.loadMaps(); };`

Comment: ok, so in local you've <1.5 and in prod you've >=1.5. You should really write precisely the gem's versions in your gemfile. This will save your back.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction. For others: I ran `gem update gmaps4rails` and got v 1.5.2, and then ran `rails generate gmaps4rails:install` to make sure I had the latest assets. I then updated my gemfile to require >= 1.5.2. Finally, I precompiled everything and pushed up to Heroku: It works! Thank you again for all your help and for your work in developing it. This really is a fantastic gem!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem after upgrading gmaps4rails.

The problem was changes to the file names and structure of the generated js files.

In application.js

There is now a gmaps4rails.base.js that needs to be included in the bundled assets. This is where the method that can't be found is.

```
//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base.js
```

also

```
//= require gmaps4rails/googlemaps.js
```

is now

```
//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.googlemaps.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mileage may vary - I don't know what version of Rails or GMaps4Rails you're using, but when I ran into this problem with Rails 3.2.16/Gmaps4Rails v2 (commit 52d7161409a060ddeabc87aa3c10049adc5edd4d, per the instructions [here](https://github.com/JonKernPA/gmaps), in the section **Add Map Javascript**:

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&sensor=false&libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```